# How to replace a character from a string using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to replace charecter "/" to "-" from string using jquery.

I want as below:

```
06/01/2013 to 06-01-2013
```

In My Case:

I am taking a value from input box

```
<input id="from-date" value="06/01/2013" name="from-date"/>

fdate = $("#from-date").val();
fdate.replace('/','-');
console.log(fdate);
```

but it return same `string(06/01/2013)`.

Comment: Your problem is that the `replace` function returns a value. And when you create questions please look at the duplicates that are suggested ....

Comment: thanks I did same as you are telling but It was not work for me as there is my some my mistake. So I post my actual issue here.

thanks again to suggest me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need jQuery but the standard replace function with the proper regex syntax :

```
fdate = fdate.replace(/\//g, '-');
```

Note that `replace` doesn't change the string you pass but returns a new one. Note also you need to pass the `g` flag so that all occurrences are replaced.